# Two ways to implement an application invoving serial communication

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, serial-port

I am in the process of writing an application, that involves serial communication with a device among other things. (in C#). I have seen some sample code, in concrete two examples.

In the first example, the code is based on a Background control which has a while loop that checks if there is data read from the serial port (another control) and when it does do some processing

```
 private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{  serialPort1.Open();
 while (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == false)
     {        
       if (serialPort1.BytesToRead >= 240)
        {
         serialPort1.Read(RDATA, 0, 240);
         //Some other process

        }
     }
 serialPort1.Close();
}
```

The second example is quite different. This involves delegates and events. In this case the serial port (created in code) has an event "DataReceived". To this we add an event handler

```
ComPort.DataReceived += 
              new System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived_1);
```

and then the port_DataReceived_1 function is defined, in which the input data is read

```
    private void port_DataReceived_1(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
 {
   InputData = ComPort.ReadExisting();
   if (InputData != String.Empty)
      {
       this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(SetText), new object[] { InputData });
       }
 }

private void SetText(string text)
 {
   this.rtbIncoming.Text += text;
  }
```

Anyway, I can see two different styles of coding serial communication here. On one hand we have a constant polling (through while) that would block the rest of the program if it weren't on another thread. It is done in a different thread though. 
On the other hand we have interruptions in which the processing is done only when an event happens and not the rest of the time. It is all done on the main thread though.

My question is which of these ways would be preferable. I am imaging that the first method, even if it is on a different thread takes a lot of resources of the computer, maybe even taking the load of the CPU to 100% or something. 
I am more inclined to do the second one but then again it is all in one thread. 
Any recommendations, advice on this?

(My application will involve not only serial communication but maybe processing on the data received, perhaps even machine learning)

Comment: That first snippet is rather horribly broken, it burns 100% core, but that's only because it is bad code, not because the approach is fundamentally wrong.  It can be a lot more convenient if the protocol is convoluted.  A third option is to use async code that awaits ReadAsync() on the BaseStream.  You'll have to decide for yourself.

Comment: What is the thing in concrete that makes it bad code?

Comment: It loops over and over again, waiting for BytesToRead to get large enough.  Burning 100% core, accomplishing nothing. No point to that, just call Read().  He probably did this so he could see CancellationPending change.  Just close the port instead, makes Read() fail.  Or don't bother at all, a port should normally always be open for the lifetime of the app.  There is a lot of bad SerialPort code out there, watch out.

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely go with the second option, which is likely handled by an [I/O Completion Port](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198.aspx) thread. If you're writing a WinForms application then you'll need to make sure to check the [InvokeRequired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx) flag and perform any UI manipulation on the main thread by passing a delegate to the [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx) method.

Comment: I see. So the second option is after all done in a different thread, isn't it? I didn't see that. And that is why it uses this.BeginInvoke to call the SetText function that affects the UI with setTextCallback which is a delegate!

Comment: Yep, you got it! FYI, in general you should call `EndInvoke` in the `BeginInvoke` handler. In this particular case it's probably safe to just use the non-async Invoke.